# memory limit and slow upload using class upload php

Tags: php, file-upload

i am creating upload image using class upload from https://www.verot.net/
my problem: output image 2 (real photo and edit-resize photo).
all work but it wasting time while processing upload.
and when i check size real photo before and after upload, size not same.

```
$counter=1;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $handle = new Upload($file);
        if ($handle->uploaded)
        {
            $handle->Process("real");
            $handle->dir_chmod = 0777;
            //$handle->jpeg_quality = 85;
            //jenis file yang diijinkan
            $handle->allowed = array('image/*');//VALIDASI UPLOAD GAMBAR
            //$handle->image_resize          = false;

            /*----first-START----*/
             if ($handle->processed) {
                ${'pathPhotoReal'.$counter} = 'real/'.$handle->file_dst_name;
                echo ${'pathPhotoReal'.$counter}."<br>";
                ${'namaFoto'.$counter}  = $_POST['text'.$counter];
                echo ${'namaFoto'.$counter}."<br>";
                }
             else {
                // one error occured
                echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '';
            }
            /*----first-FINISH----*/

            // we now process the image a second time, with some other settings
            //$handle->allowed = array('image/*');
            $handle->image_ratio = true;
            $handle->image_ratio_fill = true;
            $handle->image_resize     = true;
            $handle->image_x          = 300;
            $handle->image_y          = 300;
            $handle->Process('edit');

            /*----second-START----*/
             if ($handle->processed) {
                ${'pathFotoEdit'.$counter} = 'edit/'.$handle->file_dst_name;
                echo ${'pathFotoEdit'.$counter}."<br>";
                }
             else {
                // one error occured
                echo '  Error: ' . $handle->error . '';
            }
            /*----second-FINISH----*/

            $counter = $counter + 1;
            //$handle->clean();
        else {
            // if we're here, the upload file failed for some reasons
            // i.e. the server didn't receive the file
            echo '  File not upload ' . $handle->error . '';
            echo($handle->log);
        }
    }
```

in my last code using else{**echo '  File not upload ' . $handle->error . '';**}
it always show, inside folder pathPhoto have saved photo inside. i think upload success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the folder permissions from filezilla.
With this you can know if the server allows you to make those persmisos